# Math Captcha in Securimage is not working

Tags: php, captcha

I use https://github.com/dapphp/securimage because it has a math problem recaptcha but I'm a bit confused in their documentation. I try to use this code but not working.

```
require_once 'securimage/securimage.php';
$options = array('captcha_type' => Securimage::SI_CAPTCHA_MATHEMATIC);
Securimage::getCaptchaHtml($options);
```

it shows the default and not the math problem. did I set it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `Securimage::getCaptchaHtml()` and pass options, it isn't able to pass any options that directly affect the settings of the captcha image (e.g. font, colors, captcha type etc).

You can see the list of accepted options to `getCaptchaHtml()` [here](https://github.com/dapphp/securimage/blob/master/securimage.php#L1202).

If you'd like to switch to the math captcha, I would suggest editing `config.inc.php` in your Securimage directory and set the captcha type there.  An example [`config.inc.php.SAMPLE`](https://github.com/dapphp/securimage/blob/master/config.inc.php.SAMPLE) file is included with newer versions.  Add the `captcha_type => Securimage::SI_CAPTCHA_MATHEMATIC,` to config.inc.php and the settings will be applied.

Alternatively, you can edit securimage.php or securimage_show.php to change the captcha type, but when you upgrade you may lose the settings which is why it's better to use config.inc.php.